# Are there any concurrent containers in C++11?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, concurrency, c++11, blockingqueue

In particular, I am looking for a blocking queue. Is there such a thing in C++11? If not, what are my other options? I really don't want to go down to the thread level myself anymore. Way too error-prone.

Comment: +1, Interesting Q.Scott Meyers asked this in C++0x days [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t732306-concurrent-containers.html).It would be interesting to know how this has changed post C++11.

Comment: Very easy to turn a standard queue into a blocking queue using primitives

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[According to Diego Dagum from Microsoft's Visual C++ Team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/concurrent-containers/):

> A recurrent question (well, one of the many) is about STL containers
> and whether they are thread safe.
>
> Taking Stephan’s words here, the reality is that they aren’t, not as a
> bug but as a feature: having every member function of every STL
> container acquiring an internal lock would annihilate performance. As
> a general purpose, highly reusable library, it wouldn’t actually
> provide correctness either: the correct level to place locks is
> determined by what the program is doing. In that sense, individual
> member functions don’t tend to be such correct level.

[The Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) (PPL) includes several containers that provide thread-safe access to their elements:

- The [concurrent_vector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355343.aspx) is a sequence container class that allows random access to any element. It enables concurrency-safe append, element access, iterator access and iterator traversal operations.
- The [concurrent_queue Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx) is a sequence container class that allows first-in, first-out access to its elements. It enables a limited set of concurrency-safe operations, such as push and try_pop, to name a few.

Some samples [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/concrtextras).

Also interesting: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html.

Comment: yeach. but problem is - its just for windows =(

Comment: I don't think the concurrent_queue Class is strictly FIFO: _"Here, concurrency-safe means pointers or iterators are always valid. It's not a guarantee of element initialization, or of a particular traversal order."_
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-containers-and-objects?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 15):

C++11 does not provide concurrent containers by itself. However, there are library options.
Besides the already mentioned PPL, don't forget the Intel TBB library.

It has a concurrent `queue`, `hash_map`, `set` and `vector` implementation. But it's not only a thread-safe container library, it also comes with parallel version of standard algorithms (for-loop, reduce, sort,...).

[Intel TBB website](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

Comment: Can you give me the link of concurrent set?

Answer (score 10):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned [moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue). We have been using it for quite some time and it performs very well. It is specific that its implementation is lock-free, which immediately brings an enormous speed. Other reasons for using it (quoting from the official site):

> There are not that many full-fledged lock-free queues for C++. Boost
> has one, but it's limited to objects with trivial assignment operators
> and trivial destructors, for example. Intel's TBB queue isn't
> lock-free, and requires trivial constructors too. There's many
> academic papers that implement lock-free queues in C++, but usable
> source code is hard to find, and tests even more so.

Some benchmarks and comparisons are available [here](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2014/a-fast-general-purpose-lock-free-queue-for-c++#benchmarks), [here](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/the-worlds-fastest-logger-vs-g3log/) and [here](http://joshitech.blogspot.hr/2015/02/queue-benchmark.html).

Caveat: in a case of multiple producers, the order of popped elements is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of pushed elements (@IgorLevicki), so if you need this guarantee, look for some other option.

Comment: The problem with moodycamel implementation is that it is not FIFO (i.e. the order of popped elements is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of pushed elements) so it is not a universal solution.

Comment: @IgorLevicki Yes, you are right. The only guarantee provided is that elements from the same producer will keep their relative ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The containers' interfaces have simply not been designed with this objective. For the interfaces they use, a lock visible to the client is really the only way you could accomplish this while guaranteeing correctness and predictable behaviour. It would also be terribly inefficient because the number of acquisitions would be very high (relative to a good implementation).

**Solution 1**

Pass by value (where applicable).

**Solution 2**

Create a collection of simple bolt-on implementations that you can use to pass containers while holding a scope lock (consider it pseudo c++):

```
template <typename TCollection>
class t_locked_collection {
public:
    t_locked_collection(TCollection& inCollection, t_lock& lock) : collection(inCollection), d_lock(lock), d_nocopy() {
    }

    TCollection& collection;
    // your convenience stuff
private:
    t_scope_lock d_lock;
    t_nocopy d_nocopy;
};
```

then the caller pairs the lock with the collection, and then you update your interfaces over to use (pass by) the container type where appropriate. It's just a poor man's class extension.

This locked container is one simple example, and there are a few other variants. This is the route I chose because it really allows you to use the granularity level which is ideal for your program, even though it not as transparent (syntactically) as locked methods. It's also relatively easy to adapt existing programs. At least it behaves in a predictable manner, unlike collections with internal locks.

Another variant would be:

```
template <typename TCollection>
class t_lockable_collection {
public:
// ...
private:
    TCollection d_collection;
    t_mutex d_mutex;
};

// example:
typedef t_lockable_collection<std::vector<int> > t_lockable_int_vector;
```

...where a type similar to `t_locked_collection` could be used to expose the underlying collection. Not to imply that approach is foolproof, just fool resistant.

Comment: with "pass by value" due you mean pass the complete container by value in order to create a copy and work on the copy? Or pass the items of the container by value? Please elaborate.

Comment: @steffen pass the container's elements by value. considering the interface many containers take, this (**Solution 1**) is far from an optimal solution. the approach is also nearly useless wrt correctness, unless you are willing to write a ton of exception handling and use a ton of shared pointers.

Answer (score 1):

My version of a concurrent undordered map
    namespace concurrency
    {

```
template<typename T,typename T1>
class unordered_bucket: private std::unordered_map<T,T1>
{
mutable std::recursive_mutex m_mutex;

public:
T1 &operator [](T a)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_mutex);
    return std::unordered_map<T,T1>::operator [](a);
}

size_t size() const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_mutex);
    return  std::unordered_map<T,T1>::size();
}

vector<pair<T,T1>> toVector() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_mutex);

    vector<pair<T,T1>> ret;
    for(const pair<T,T1> &p:*this)
    {
        ret.push_back(p);
    }
    return ret;
}

bool find(const T &t) const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_mutex);
    if(this->std::unordered_map<T,T1>::find(t) == this->end())
        return false;  //not found
    return true;
}
void erase()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_mutex);
    this->unordered_map<T,T1>::erase(this->begin(),this->end());
}
void erase(const T &t)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(m_mutex);
    this->unordered_map<T,T1>::erase(t);
}
};

#define BUCKETCOUNT 10
template<typename T,typename T1>
class ConcurrentMap
{
std::vector<unordered_bucket<T,T1>> m_v;
public:
ConcurrentMap():m_v(BUCKETCOUNT){}   //using 10 buckets

T1 &operator [](T a)
{
    std::hash<T> h;
    return m_v[h(a)%BUCKETCOUNT][a];
}

size_t size() const noexcept {
    size_t cnt=0;

    for(const unordered_bucket<T,T1> &ub:m_v)
        cnt=cnt+ub.size();

    return  cnt;
}

vector<pair<T,T1>> toVector() const
{
    vector<pair<T,T1>> ret;
    for(const unordered_bucket<T,T1> &u:m_v)
    {
        const vector<pair<T,T1>> &data=u.toVector();
        ret.insert(ret.end(),data.begin(),data.end());
    }
    return ret;
}

bool find(const T &t) const
{
    for(const unordered_bucket<T,T1> &u:m_v)
        if(true == u.find(t))
            return true;
    return false;
}
void erase()
{
    for(unordered_bucket<T,T1> &u:m_v)
        u.erase();
}
void erase(const T &t)
{
    std::hash<T> h;
    unordered_bucket<T,T1> &ub = m_v[h(t)%BUCKETCOUNT];
    ub.erase(t);
}
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no concurrent containers in C++11.

But the following header class provides concurrent queue, stack and priority containers using std::deque.

[BlockingCollection](https://github.com/CodeExMachina/BlockingCollection) is a C++11 thread safe collection class that is modeled after the .NET BlockingCollection class.