# Can std::queue concurrent insertion in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, openmp

This short code in below is based on the breath first search. I would hope to parallel it with OpenMP but have no success. Is there any way to have multiple threads inserting items to queue using OpenMP parallel construct ?

---

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  queue<int> q;
  int v;
  int cnt = 0;

  for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
    q.push(i);
    cnt += 1;
  }

  while (!q.empty()) {
    v = q.front();
    q.pop();
    cout << "v=" << v << ",";

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
      int j = v*i + 3;
      if ( j < 13) {
        q.push(j);
        cnt += 1;
      }
    }

  }

  cout << endl << q.size() << endl;
  cout << "count=" << cnt << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: std::queue::push is not thread safe, so it's not possible with queue

Answer (score 3):

> Can std::queue concurrent insertion in OpenMP?

In general, NO. None of the standard containers are safe. You will have to provide external locks.

See this related question on Stack Overflow: [Are there any concurrent containers in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7817364/608639). Also see [Concurrent Unordered Associative Containers for C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3425.html) from the working group and [C++11 STL containers and thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12931787/608639) from Stack Overflow.