# Difference between LMDB and STX btrees

Tags: b-tree, lmdb, stx

I would like to use in-memory btree. I am considering LMDB and STX.
I appreciate help in understanding the difference between them. Among the others in context with concurrency (I'm not sure if STX supports it)

Answer (score 0):

STX implements in-memory (non-persistent) B+trees as C++ templates, LMDB implements memory-mapped (persistent) B+trees as a C library. While LMDB can deliver the performance of an in-memory data structure, it is more than that. If you only need in-memory it may be overkill for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering about the STX concurrency support as I would need such feature. What level of concurrency does STX support? Thanks again.

Comment: STX implements the STL container interface. STL containers are not threadsafe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817364/are-there-any-concurrent-containers-in-c11